# Is there something similar to ENUM in IronPython

Tags: enums, ironpython

i am writing a customization script for a technical program (ANSYS ACT) which is using IronPython
(Python script engine version 2.7.0.40 )

When using standard CPhython I quite often use the Enum Module to do make options more readable.
Something like that:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class StressType (Enum):    
    ElemMean = auto()
    NodeAveraged = auto()
    ElemNodeUnaveraged = auto()
    
def doSomething (stress, stresstype):    
   if not isinstance(stresstype, StressType):   # Type checking
        raise TypeError('Type Error')
   if stresstype is StressType.ElemMean:
        do something with stress ...    
   elif (stresstype is StressType.NodeAveraged):
       do something else with stress 
    ...
```

However in the Customization Environment this Module does not seem to exist. I got this Error Message:

```
Starting Python script engine version 2.7.0.40 for extension xxx.
No module named enum
```

Is there something similar for Ironpython like the enum datatype?
Best would be a native datatype, so no modules have to be installed.

Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [aenum](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/) library<sup>1</sup>, besides having a bit more to offer than the stdlib enum library, works on Python 2.7 as well as 3.3+

--

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Hi Ethan, thank you for the hint! I decided to go with the enum34 package. This helps.

Comment: @Nisse:  Cool.  If you need `StrEnum`, `Flag`, or `IntFlag`, you'll need to switch to aenum as those are not present in enum34.

Answer (score -1):

[IronPython is struggling to keep up with Python 3](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3).

[Enums were added to Python in version 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

Your version of IronPython is  2.7.0.40, which does not have enums. Either update to the current version of IronPython, and suffer through the incomplete support of Python 3, or choose a different Python implementation, or do not try to use enums until IronPython catches up.

Comment: Hi + Thank you. Unfortunately using the customazation interface I am forced to work with this version. So I need  to avoid this enum functionality. Are there any suggestions how to do so and still have readable code? I guess just using global list of strings?

Comment: That would be reasonable.

Comment: @MikeSlinn: Asking to have your answer up-voted and accepted when there is no evidence from the OP that your answer was useful is inappropriate.  (Note: that comment was deleted after the answer was accepted.)

Comment: @EthanFurman I think you are completely off base here. Why the hostility?

Comment: @MikeSlinn: Hostility, no; irritation, yes.  Did you ask to have your answer up-voted and accepted?  Had the OP said "thank you", "that helped", or anything of the kind before you asked for that?  If I'm wrong, I'm happy to delete my comments.  If I'm not wrong, I'm not off base.

Comment: @EthanFurman Hostility, like all forms of communication, is an interaction involving 2 parties. If one party says, "Your behavior seems hostile", then the other party can react in various ways. You reacted with denial and a further attack. Peace. Please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/03/17/stack-overflow-culture/

Comment: @MikeSlinn: How should I have voiced my concerns over your inappropriate behavior so that it did not seem hostile?  Would it be hostile to note that you still have not responded to my initial complaint, but have only focused on my delivery?  I'm asking both questions in all seriousness - I'm willing to learn and improve, but it feels to me like you are side-stepping my original assertion by redirecting the focus on me.

Comment: @EthanFurman I appreciate what you are saying, and I would like to share with you a blog post I am writing on the subject. Your feedback and any suggestions would be most welcome. I am mslinn@mslinn.com and if you email me, I will respond with the current draft. We can continue the discussion offline.

Comment: https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/04/18/so-culture.html

Comment: @MikeSlinn: You still have not responded in any way to my complaint about your actions -- not an apology, not a defense, not an explanation, nothing.  It seems that you are not engaging with me in good faith, so I have no desire to engage any further with you.

Comment: The article is my response. Be well.